# C++ vector gets emptied after passing it to function

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `City` class that holds a vector of `lot` objects.
My class looks like this:

```
class City{
   public:
   City();
   City(int lots);
   std::vector<lot> houses;
```

```
City::City(){
   for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++){
      houses.push_back(House());
   }
}

City::City(int lots){
   for(int i = 0; i < lots; i++){
      houses.push_back(House());
   }
}
```

I have a different class called `Mayor` that does a wide variety of things using a `City`.
It looks like this:

```
class Mayor{
    City c;
    Mayor(City c);
    announce();

}
```

```
Mayor::Mayor(City c){
    std::cout<<"This town has "<<c.lots.size()<<" houses"<<endl;
    c=c;
    std::cout<<"This town has "<<c.lots.size()<<" houses"<<endl;
}

void Mayor::announce(){

    std::cout<<"This town has "<<c.lots.size()<<" houses"<<endl;
    return;
}
```

Now my main program does this, where I'm finding a mistake.

```
void main(){
    City newyork = City(101);
    std::cout<<"This town has "<<newyork.lots.size()<<" houses"<<endl;

    Mayor cuomo = Mayor(newyork);

    cuomo.announce();
}
```

Since New York has a 100 houses, then Cuomo should announce 100 houses. But instead, Cuomo will announce NY has 0 houses. I don't understand why or where my vector gets wiped clean.

This is my output:

```
This town has 100 houses
This town has 100 houses
This town has 100 houses
This town has 0 houses
```

I literally have no idea why this is happening, and I can't get anything done if this piece doesn't work. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `c=c;` -- Which `c` is which?  Why are you naming your variables the same, plus with short one-letter names such as `c`?  You should get into the habit of naming your variables with meaningful, unambiguous names.

Comment: Welcome! I can't see what `.lots` is. Also, why don't you use constructor member initializer list for the `Mayor` class? Also, note the condition ` for(int i = 0; i > 101; i++)`, *while i is more than 101, do...*.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you! It makes sense for me now - ill definetely ccreate that habit!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to declare a vector like this

```
std::vector<int> houses;
```

Not like this

```
std::vector<lot> houses;
```

and also put void before announce method
like this while declaration

```
void announce();
```

Comment: Note, that there are more than one problem.

Comment: Yeah there are also problem with function declaration